# Cannot automated sign in for dropbox.com through Selenium (Java)

Tags: selenium

Hello I am new to automation and i have tried automating dropbox.com sign in but my code is failing after clicking on sign in link. i am not able to pass the values (username and password) in the frame of the sign in box. Following is my code.

```
 import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;


public class Drop_box {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.dropbox.com");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='sign-in']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='pyxl1851']")).sendKeys("123@gmail.com");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='pyxl1854']")).sendKeys("1234");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='regular-login-forms']/form[1]/div[3]/button")).click();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a#sign-in")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div#index-sign-in-modal input[name='login_email']")).sendKeys("email");
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div#index-sign-in-modal input[name='login_password']")).sendKeys("password");
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div#index-sign-in-modal div.sign-in-text")).click();
```

If you prefer xpath over css selectors, then use following lines of code:

```
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='sign-in']")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='index-sign-in-modal']//input[@name='login_email']")).sendKeys("email");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='index-sign-in-modal']//input[@name='login_password']")).sendKeys("password");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='index-sign-in-modal']//div[@class='sign-in-text']")).click();
```